# Convert date timestamp(mm/dd/yy hh:mm) to date(mm/dd/yy) in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have loaded a csv file into snowflake and one of the date columns is in the format mm/dd/yy hh:mm (ex: 9/30/21 22:30). When I run this command

```
Select TO_VARCHAR(TO_DATE(operation_date,'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm'),'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

I get this error:

> Can't parse '9/30/21 22:30' as date with format 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm'

Can someone please tell me how I can fix this issue, so my final output would look something like: `09/30/21`

Answer (score 2):

the given string is `'MM/DD/YY hh24:mi'` format, and the error message format should have been `'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mi'`. When these are used together, and merged via COALESCE or NVL via a TRY_ function, you can merge the two types.

```
SELECT 
    column1 as operation_date,
    try_TO_DATE(operation_date,'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mi') as date_a,
    try_TO_DATE(operation_date,'MM/DD/YY hh24:mi') as date_b,
    nvl(date_a, date_b) as unified_date,
    TO_VARCHAR(unified_date,'MM/DD/YYYY')
from values
    ('30/9/2021 22:30'),
    ('9/30/21 22:30')
;
```

gives:

| OPERATION_DATE | DATE_A | DATE_B | UNIFIED_DATE | TO_STRING |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30/9/2021 22:30 | 2021-09-30 | null | 2021-09-30 | 09/30/2021 |
| 9/30/21 22:30 | null | 2021-09-30 | 2021-09-30 | 09/30/2021 |

Comment: Thanks a ton!! you really helped me out.

Comment: @user2960654 glad to hear. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer